# differences between List(), Array() and new List(), new Array() in Scala

Tags: scala

I know that when you type:

```
val list = List(2,3)
```

you are accessing the apply method of the List object which returns a List. What I can't understand is why is this possible when the List class is abstract and therefore cannot be directly instanciated(new List() won't compile)?
I'd also like to ask what is the difference between:

```
val arr = Array(4,5,6)
```

and

```
val arr = new Array(4, 5, 6)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I started writing that the easy way to determine this is to look at the sources for the methods you're calling, which are available from the [ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html). However, the various levels of indirection that are gone through to actually build a list give lie to the term 'easy'! It's worth having a look through if you want, starting from the `apply` method in the `List` object which is defined as follows:

```
override def apply[A](xs: A*): List[A] = xs.toList
```

You may or may not know that a parameter of the form `xs : A*` is treated internally as a `Seq`, which means that we're calling the `toList` method on a `Seq`, which is defined in `TraversableOnce`. This then delegates to a generic `to` method, which looks for an implicit 
`CanBuildFrom` which actually constructs the list. So what you're getting back is some implementation of `List` which is chosen by the `CanBuildFrom`. What you actually get is a `scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon`, which implements a singly-linked list.

Luckily, the behaviour of `Array.apply` is a little easier to look up:

```
  def apply[T: ClassTag](xs: T*): Array[T] = {
    val array = new Array[T](xs.length)
    var i = 0
    for (x <- xs.iterator) { array(i) = x; i += 1 }
    array
  }
```

So, `Array.apply` just delegates to `new Array` and then sets elements appropriately.

Answer (score 8):

The `List` class is `sealed` and `abstract`. It has two concreate implementations

1. `Nil` which represents an empty list
2. `::[B]` which represents a non empty list with head and tail. [`::[B]` in the documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.%24colon%24colon)

When you call `List.apply` it will jump through some hoops and supply you with an instance of the `::[B]` case class.

About array: `new Array(4, 5, 6)` will throw a compile error as the constructor of array is defined like this: `new Array(_length: Int)`. The `apply` method of the `Array` companion object uses the arguments to create a new instance of an `Array` (with the help of `ArrayBuilder`).

Comment: Worth noting that `Array.apply` only falls back to using an `ArrayBuilder` if you're trying to build an array if there's no `ClassTag` available for the contained type, and it's not something with a primitive JVM representation.